# how can I change default python version in pythonanywhere?

Tags: python, django, web-deployment, pythonanywhere

I am trying to deploy my Django application on **pythonanywhere** through manual-configuration. I selected Python 3.6.When I opened the console and type "python --version" It is showing python 2.7 instead of 3.6. How can I change this?
Please help me.

Comment: this help page may also be relevant? https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/SaveAndRunPythonVersion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python 3.6 is available as python3.6 in a console on PythonAnywhere.

Comment: It doesn't work. I fixed python 3.6 from settings but console command results 2.7.

Comment: Worth noting that there is no space between `python` and `3.6` when you type it in to Bash.   For example, `python3.6 /home/myusername/script.py`

Answer (score 2):

to set your default python version from 2.7 to 3.7 run the command below
$ alias python=python3
that's it now check the version 
$ python --version 
it should be solved

Answer (score 1):

you can check your python version in several way. Here are some way.

**in Interpreter**

```
>>import sys
>>sys.version
# output: python 3.6.0
```

**in bash or console**

```
python --version
```

Now for solving the version problem `2.x to 3.x`

in your `bash`

> > $ alias python=python3
> >
> > $ python --version

After doing this your environment for `python` it will interpret as `python3`

Answer (score 0):

Try to type "python3 --version". This can work on linux, but I am not sure whether it works on pythonanywhere